# Iterate and write to an ObjectOutputStream

Tags: objectoutputstream

When should I close an `ObjectOutputStream` using the following code? Thank you all...

```
 try{
    ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    AnObject[] array = new AnObject[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++){
        array[i] = new AnObject();
        output.writeObject(array[i]);
    }
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    }
catch(IOException e){
      processException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're done using it. You should `flush()` after sending, to force through all the data added to the stream's buffer to your underlying stream (`Object*Streams` are wrappers to your client's `OutputStream`), even if the stream's buffer isn't full.

Also, no need to flush before closing, because `output.close()` calls `flush()`.

It looks like you close it after sending data, so unless you have more stuff to send through your client's stream, you're closing properly.